# How to create parent classes which could be derived only mutually exclusive way?

Tags: c++

I have two interface implementations, class A and class B. I want to restrict users/clients of my library from creating new derived classes which inherit from both of them as class A and class B perform the same task in different ways.

Comment: there is some information related at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1492.pdf, but it says that there is no solution to this, rather than carefully documenting the class.

Comment: Are you sure inheritance is right approach to your problem? You want library users to choose a single behavior. This seems to me like [policy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design) or it's runtime analog [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).