# c++ How to static_assert that derived class doesn't inherit from some class

Tags: c++, static-assert

Let's say that I have two classes `Yes` and `No`. I want to express that deriving from them is mutually exclusive. That is any class can derive from either `Yes` or `No`, but can't derive from both at the same time. I would like to enforce this by using a `static_assert`.

So far I know that I can use `std::is_base_of` to check for inheritance, but I don't know how to express "any type that is derived from this class". Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

class Yes;
class No;

class Yes {
  static_assert(
    std::negation<std::is_base_of<No, (how to name this type?)>>::value,
    "Classes deriving from Yes cannot derive from No"
  );
};
```

Another way to do it would be to somehow express that given constraint must be true for
**all existing types**. But I don't know how to express it either and don't think it is
even possible. Here is another example of how something like this could be implemented:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

class Yes;
class No;

"for all existing types T": static_assert(
  std::negation<std::conjunction<std::is_base_of<Yes, T>, std::is_base_of<No, T>>,
  "type T cannot inherit both from Yes and No"
);
```

So my question is: Is it even possible to express this constraints? And if so, how can I do it?

Comment: You are not going to be able to do this validation inside of `Yes` (or `No`) itself, since it doesn't know anything about derived types (which can't exist at that point anyway), unless you use something like [CRTP](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/crtp).  And there is no code syntax to do the validation on "all existing types", either.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's sad. But isn't there some way to refer to type of `*this` and then "copy" static_assertion with type changed to derived type when deriving from `Yes` or `No`?

Comment: At compile-time, `*this` is not the derived type for code that is inside of `Yes` or `No` itself.

Comment: I know. I was hoping it would be always changed to current type. But I see yours suggestion about CRTP and it might be a way to go.

Comment: "*I was hoping it would be always changed to current type*" - how do you expect the compiler to be able to do that? When the derived type may not even exist yet at the point where `*this` is evaluated? Think about it.

Comment: Apparently there was no answer 7 years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30003496 / https://wg21.link/N1492

Comment: @Artyer Thank you. That definitely closes this question.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze may become possible with "deducing this" in C++23 but you have to put it in a method that is called.

Answer (score 0):

There is no code syntax to do the validation on "all existing types".

I think the only way you will be able to do this kind of validation inside of `Yes` (or `No`) itself is if you use [Curious Recursive Template Pattern](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/crtp) (I'm not sure if this will even work), eg:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Derived>
class Yes;

template<typename Derived>
class No {
  static_assert(
    std::negation<std::is_base_of<Yes<Derived>, Derived>>::value,
    "Classes deriving from No cannot derive from Yes"
  );
};

template<typename Derived>
class Yes {
  static_assert(
    std::negation<std::is_base_of<No<Derived>, Derived>>::value,
    "Classes deriving from Yes cannot derive from No"
  );
};
```

```
class MyYesClass : public Yes<MyYesClass> // OK
{
...
};

class MyNoClass : public No<MyNoClass> // OK
{
...
};

class MyYesNoClass : public Yes<MyYesNoClass>, No<MyYesNoClass> // Not OK
{
...
};
```

Comment: It seems very promising. However it creates another question. Can I enforce that `Derived` type is always type of deriving class? What if I wrote `class NaughtyClass: public Yes<MyYesClass>, No<MyNoClass> {};`?

Comment: Also, I can't compile your snippet. Clang says "error: incomplete type 'MyYesClass' used in type trait expression".

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze "*Can I enforce that `Derived` type is always type of deriving class?*" - CRTP uses the honor system, the deriving class is expected to pass in itself, but there is no way (that I know of) to *enforce* that, no.

Comment: Thank you. So it seems that all of that juggling is in the end unnecessary, because stating in documentation that you cannot derive from both Yes and No is basically the same honor system that I would get if I used CRTP.

Comment: Within CRTP, `Derived` is incomplete, so the `static_assert` might not be placed there. Might be placed in destructor (or constructors) though (but require instantiation on those methods).